# Module 'firebase_analytics' not found

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a problem,

I tried to publish a new version of my app on the apple store and it gave this problem:

Module 'firebase_analytics' not found

Has anyone ever experienced this?

[Module 'firebase_analytics' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Rnd.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you add analytics to your podfile.

```
target 'Runner' do
 pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

The other thing is to go to the ios directory and execute the command.

```
 pod clean
 pod install
```

Finally you could run the following commands in the root directory.

```
 flutter clean
 flutter pub get
```